Animation about an inescapable land of pleasures
I am looking for the name of a short animation.
The main character finds himself in a land of pleasures, and when he tries to escape, the owner (a hippo, whale or some other big animal) tells him that he can only do so when he has spent his last coin. So the main character begins spending all his coins, gorging himself on food, sex, gambling, etc. But when he’s about to leave, he has still one last coin, which he uses in a slot machine and ends up becoming rich once again...
It should be an 80s or 90s animation, I think.

Welcome to Movies & TV SE. Can you please [edit] your question to specify when and where you saw that short?

Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in?   Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Hello, everyone!
Thanks for your feedback, and your corrections, Wezlprmft.
I believe I saw it around late 90's, early 2000's. I believe it was either British or Canadian, as the language was English, and the animation style fancies me of those countries. It was quite colorful, but had an underlying sense of dread.

@J.RRomero - Ask and ye shall receive. But beware, if you ask too many questions, you may not be allowed to leave... :-)

Could this be Exit (1990)?

A group of youths entertain themselves in a giant theme park,
blissfully ignorant of the regulation that prevents them from leaving
until every credit is spent...




